# Autocorrelation function of arbitary random process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Autocorrelation function of a random process is defined as follows:
$$R(X_t,X_s)=E[X_tX_s]$$
Given a random process defined as
$$X_t= \xi_1f_1(t)+...+\xi_nf_n(t) $$
where $f_1,...,f_n$ -
arbitrary numeric functions;$ \xi_1...\xi_n$-uncorrelated random variables with variance $\sigma_1^2...\sigma_n^2$. Find it autocorrelation function

My attempt:
$$R(X_t,X_s)=E[(\xi_1f_1(t)+...+\xi_nf_n(t))(\xi_1f_1(s)+...+\xi_nf_n(s))] = f_1(t)f_1(s)E[\xi_1^2]+...+f_n(t)f_n(s)E[\xi_n^2]+E[\xi_1]E[\xi_n](f_n(s)f_1(t)+f_1(s)f_n(t))+...= f_1(t)f_1(s)\sigma_1^2+...+f_n(t)f_n(s)\sigma_n^2+f_1(t)f_1(s)(E[\xi_1])^2+...+f_n(t)f_n(s)(E[\xi_n])^2+E[\xi_1]E[\xi_n](f_n(s)f_1(t)+f_1(s)f_n(t))+... $$
But how to get rid of mathematical expectations?

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume $n=2$ to begin with. Also I'm assuming the vars $\xi_i$ have zero mean (the data seems missing).

Then $E[ \xi_i^2] =\sigma_i^2$ and $ E[ \xi_i \xi_j ]=0$ for $i\ne j$. Also remember that $f_i(t)$ is deterministic.

$$\begin{align}
R(X_t,X_s)&=E[(\xi_1f_1(t)+\xi_ 2 f_2(t))(\xi_1f_1(s)+\xi_ 2 f_2(s))] \\
&= g_1(t,s) \sigma_1^2 + g_2(t,s) \sigma_2^2 \\
\end{align}
$$

where $g_i(t,s)= f_i(t)f_i(s)$.

Can you go on from here ?

Comment: If the vars $\xi_i$ have zero mean, my attempt is similar to yours, but, unfortunately, there is nothing about zero expectation in the task. Only said "these vars are uncorrelated"